# FB Graph API authentication for facebook

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, fb-graph

I used FB graph api to integrate my ios app with facebook.but when the login
webview is pop up, the first problem is it dose not have cancel button
still i have put a button an apply a action but could not able to go on that screen from where i was come.

```
NSString *url_string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=%@&redirect_uri=%@&scope=%@&type=user_agent&display=touch", facebookClientID, redirectUri, extended_permissions];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:url_string];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

CGRect webFrame = [super_view frame];

webFrame.origin.y = 0;
UIWebView *aWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webFrame];
[aWebView setDelegate:self];    
self.webView = aWebView;

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.frame = CGRectMake(5.0, 10, 150.0, 30.0);
[button setTitle:@"My Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.webView addSubview:button];
[aWebView release];

[webView loadRequest:request];  
[super_view addSubview:webView];
```

so how i can move back please some body help me.....

Comment: What does your `myAction:` method look like?

Comment: myAction: in this action i just wanted to go my previousview from where i was come

Answer (score 0):

In `myAction:` method, remove the `webView`

```
[self.webView removeFromSuperView];
```